# Getting the path of a downloaded file from a c# .NET IE Webbrowser component

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I have an application in c# which needs to be able to retrieve the file last downloaded by the `WebBrowser` component.

I.E.:

1. a web page spits out a file like 'app.exe' through an iframe or whatever.
2. The `WebBrowser` component automatically downloads the file (the default behaviour).
3. I need to, from c#, get the file path so I can open it.

Any ideas/methods would be welcome.

Please note: The file downloaded is a result of a form submission to a server side script - therefore I cannot rely on screening urls to find the extension to re-download the file using `WebClient`.

Comment: We need some context here.  The file would more then likely be created in the same directory as the application itself.

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the case; the downloaded file was not sitting next to the exe.

Context: I am making a wrapper for the mbed.org compiler and need to catch the binary file (download) that gets chucked through the browser with ajax.